# Viewmodel displaying everything

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Trying to learn and understand ViewModels as the solution for a problem I've been having. So far I have this:

```
    public class PrinterCreditsModel
{
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public int AmountAdded { get; set; }
    public string AddedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime AddedWhen { get; set; }
    public string Money { get; set; }
    public tblOption PrinterCreditFund { get; set; }
}
```

They all come from `"tblPrinterCredits"`, apart from `"PrinterCreditFund"` which comes from `"tblOption"`.

I've changed the model on the create page to use the `viewmodel`, and added the @html.labelfor etc etc for the `PrinterCreditFund` attribute, but it's just displaying everything in that database table. Any help on why, or a point in the right direction, would be appreciated :)

Thanks

This is the code for the View -

```
@model Dashboard.ViewModels.PrinterCreditsModel

@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>tblPrinterCredit</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Username, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Username, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Username, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AmountAdded, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.AmountAdded, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AmountAdded, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AddedBy, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.AddedBy, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AddedBy, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AddedWhen, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.AddedWhen, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AddedWhen, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Money, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Money, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Money, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PrinterCreditFund, htmlAttributes: new{@class = "control-label col-md-2"})
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PrinterCreditFund, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PrinterCreditFund, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
}
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Create()
    {
        ViewBag.OptionID = new SelectList(db.tblOptions, "ID", "PrinterCreditFund");
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "PrinterCreditID,Username,AmountAdded,AddedBy,AddedWhen,Money,OptionID")] tblPrinterCredit tblPrinterCredit)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {              
            db.tblPrinterCredits.Add(tblPrinterCredit);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        ViewBag.OptionID = new SelectList(db.tblOptions, "ID", "PrinterCreditFund", tblPrinterCredit.OptionID);
        return View(tblPrinterCredit);
    }
```

And this is the tblOptions model, to show whats in the table:

```
public int ID { get; set; }
public int Visible { get; set; }
public int DeleteLicense { get; set; }
public Nullable<int> ICTSurvey { get; set; }
public Nullable<int> PaidWorkSurvey { get; set; }
public Nullable<int> ICTGeneralSurvey { get; set; }
public Nullable<int> PESSCLSurvey { get; set; }
public Nullable<int> PastSurvey { get; set; }
public Nullable<int> PresentSurvey { get; set; }
public Nullable<int> Yr11Survey { get; set; }
public Nullable<int> NewScientistCount { get; set; }
public Nullable<int> UCASYear { get; set; }
public Nullable<int> OnlineSurveyActive { get; set; }
public Nullable<int> OnlineExaminationsActive { get; set; }
public string UCASFirstHalf { get; set; }
public string UCASSecondHalf { get; set; }
public string SIMSManual { get; set; }
public string SIMSApplication { get; set; }
public string SIMSAmpark { get; set; }
public string PrinterCreditFund { get; set; }
public string PrinterCreditCost { get; set; }
public string UCASIndividualFirstHalf { get; set; }
public string UCASIndividualSecondHalf { get; set; }
public string BookingSheetYear { get; set; }
public Nullable<System.DateTime> InductionDate { get; set; }
public string InductionYear { get; set; }
```

Details page as asked:

```
    @model Dashboard.tblPrinterCredit

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Details";
}

<h2>Details</h2>

<div>
    <h4>tblPrinterCredit</h4>
    <hr />
    <dl class="dl-horizontal">
        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Username)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Username)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.AmountAdded)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.AmountAdded)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.AddedBy)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.AddedBy)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.AddedWhen)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.AddedWhen)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Money)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Money)
        </dd>

        <dt>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.tblOption.UCASFirstHalf)
        </dt>

        <dd>
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.tblOption.UCASFirstHalf)
        </dd>

    </dl>
</div>
<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = Model.PrinterCreditID }) |
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</p>
```

And the details actionresult:

```
    public ActionResult Details(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        tblPrinterCredit tblPrinterCredit = db.tblPrinterCredits.Find(id);
        if (tblPrinterCredit == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(tblPrinterCredit);
    }
```

[image: Create Page]

Image above shows it. Marked in blue is what shows from the tblPrinterCredits, which should all be there. In red is from tblOption, of which only PrinterCreditFund should be showing

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76176/discussion-on-question-by-chris-barsby-viewmodel-displaying-everything).

Comment: Since you're not using an mvvm framework in the client, that tag is invalid here.